# Google Cloud Application Default Credentials Permission Denied - Quota Project not set as Default

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-auth

I'm using the Cloud Vision API for a project and I'm trying to build and run the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/vision/latest) example, but I am receiving the following error:

```
google::cloud::Status thrown: PERMISSION_DENIED: Error in non-idempotent operation: Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. 
The vision.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. 
To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds . 
error_info={reason=SERVICE_DISABLED, domain=googleapis.com, metadata={gcloud-cpp.retry.reason=non-idempotent, 
gcloud-cpp.retry.original-message=Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. 
The vision.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default.
To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .,
consumer=projects/764086051850, gcloud-cpp.retry.function=BatchAnnotateImages, service=vision.googleapis.com}}
```

I ran
`gcloud auth applicataion-default set-quota-project [project-id]`
a couple of times, with multiple different proejcts, to no avail.

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you try to set this environment variable equal to your quota project: `GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT`? It works in Python, maybe also in C++!

Comment: The other possible solution is to perform a `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<SA email>`, to use a service account instead of a user account as credential (but always without using a service account key file which is a bad practice!!). Let me know which one works!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the advice. I tried the first one and it did nothing, the second one actually produced a different error, saying "Could not create google default credentials: UNKNOWN:Invalid credentials json type." Not sure how to resolve this but I'll keep searching.

Comment: C++ libraries are not up to date (and they are pretty old, I got those error in Python/Go library 2 years ago or so). I have no magic wand if it's not up to date. Maybe open a request into the github repo, or propose a merge request yourselves! I can't help, I'm not a C++ developer! https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp

Comment: Thanks so much, I will look into that! Sadly this is for a project that requires C++, otherwise I would absolutely use Python or Go.

Answer (score 0):

This error message

> Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The vision.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds ...

...is not true, but not completely unhelpful.

I got a similar error message when using identitytoolkit.googleapis.com , invoking the REST API directly, not through a library. Just using curl etc.

I had obtained my token from `gcloud auth print-access-token` , so the error message  "Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials."  was plainly incorrect .

and "The vision.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default." was also wrong. For me, same as with you, even after setting a quota project for ADC with the suggested step of

`gcloud auth applicataion-default set-quota-project [project-id]`

..it still gives the same error message. Good for you, for trying the same thing multiple times before surrendering. I did too.  But really, we should know that it wouldn't work, because we weren't using ADC to begin with.

But it isn't completely unhelpful, because it's talking about *billing*.

The solution is described [here, in the doc explaining how to troubleshoot ADCs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/troubleshoot-adc#user-creds-client-based)

> There are two kinds of Google Cloud APIs:
>
> Resource-based APIs, which use the project associated with the resources being accessed for billing and quota.
>
> Client-based APIs, which use the project associated with the account accessing the resources for billing and quota.
>
> When you provide user credentials to authenticate to a client-based API, you must specify the project to use for billing and quota. This project is called the quota project.
>
> There are a number of ways to specify a quota project, including the following options:
>
> - Update ADC to use a different project as the quota project:
>   `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project YOUR_PROJECT`
> - If you are calling the REST or RPC API directly, **use the x-goog-user-project HTTP header** to specify a quota project in each request. For details, see Set the quota project with a REST request.

Vision and identitytoolkit are client-billed APIs, and so if you are going to use the API directly, then you need to use the **X-goog-user-project** header.

WHY, you might ask, is a fact about invoking REST APIs that have special billing requirements, described ONLY in the doc page for
troubleshooting ADCs" ?  Diabolical I tell you.  It's like telling people to read the documentation on your dishwasher to understand how to start your car.

tl;dr.
The error message is wrong. The doc is right, but is in the  wrong place. it would be better if the error message just redirected to this stackoverflow thread.